# Unchecking vb.net checkboxes

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, checkbox

I have a basic question about Vb.net.

I have a form, say "Form1" on which a checkbox "CheckBox1" triggers the pop-up of another form (say "Form2"). Form2 has a "cancel" button (say "Button1") which closes Form2 and unchecks "CheckBox1" on Form1.

The Form2 "Cancel" button code is :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click        
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
    Form1.CheckBox1.CheckState = 0
    End Sub
```

It works, but I have a problem when trying to do the same with a third form ("Form3") triggered by another CheckBox1 on Form2, despite Form3 "Cancel" button is though coded the same way in Form3 :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click        
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
    Form2.CheckBox1.CheckState = 0
    End Sub
```

When I display MsgBox(Form2.CheckBox1.CheckState) in Form3 code, it's always "0", despite it's "1" when I display MsgBox(CheckBox1.CheckState) in Form2.

Sorry for this noob question, but I can't see any explanation.
Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Switch Option Strict On, and change your `CheckState` assignments to the correct Enumeration instead of 0 or 1.

Secondly, you should avoid setting the properties of controls on different forms.

You can use the return value from `ShowDialog` to determine whether the OK or Cancel button was clicked on a Form.

So what you would do is to specify the result value of the OK and Cancel buttons in **Form2** like this:

```
    btnOK.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    btnCancel.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
```

Make sure you add the code in **Form2** to close the form when each of these are clicked:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Then in **Form1** you call Form2.ShowDialog and inspect the DialogResult value to see which button was clicked:

```
    Dim result = Form2.ShowDialog
    If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'ok button was clicked
        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
    ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        'cancel button was clicked
        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
```

As an alternative, the Form1 code can be drastically simplified when you are happy with the logic to something like this:

```
CheckBox1.Checked = (Form2.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I changed the Strict Option to "on" and followed your advices, but my problem's still here. Very frustrating.

Comment: So my question would become : how do you make to uncheck a checkbox in a form because you have checked a cancel button in another form ?

Comment: See my answer. I have expanded what I put before to make it clearer

Comment: A big "THANK YOU". It works perfectly. 
When I see your profile, I understand why you recommend to switch "Option Strict" on...
My problem was finally to be rigorous enough, as usual when coding. But my initial way was working until now... 
I'm though surprised to see that what works with the "main" form doesn't work anymore when cascading them.
Thank you very much anyway for having taken time to help a beginner like me. This is very, very kind of you. Have a good day.